# Who decides chord details in published songs?

Tags: chords, history, lead-sheets, editions

I like to make lead sheets of songs like this to learn to improvise from, condensing the published sheet music down to a single page with no turns. In working from my two copies of It's Only A Paper Moon I ran into this difference

[image: The Harold Arlen Songbook]

[image: The Great American Songbook - The Composers]

It's a subtle difference, but an interesting one. But who decided it? I can see the guitar chords being added by some editor, and I understand there are different chord choices to describe a given half-measure of notes. But are the notes themselves usually Harold Arlen's, or somebody else's? And who would have made that decision to change the bass note to fit their chord choice better?

The first source, The Harold Arlen Songbook, lists a David Bickman as the editor, and the second source The Great American Songbook - The Composers, doesn't list an editor, though both are published by Hal Leonard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Aaron is right in that arrangers and/or music editors hired by the publisher are responsible for the contents of sheet music. One thing to be aware of is that there is actually no exact formula for doing this and also no way of knowing how much input the actual composer had in the creation of the sheet music.

You have a recording/performance of a composition which the publisher decides to sell as sheet music. It is then arranged for piano/vocal (with the melody line usually included in the piano arrangement) then the chord symbols are added, usually with a guitar in mind, that may or may not match what is in the piano arrangement. Case in point: in your first example, the Gsus (or sus over G, that’s a new one!). Whoever wrote that obviously only looked at the right hand and saw G-C-D but didn’t bother looking at the root note in the left hand. Bottom line, the published sheet music can potentially be very different than the original source material. This holds true for songs that are days or decades old.

If you are looking to practice improvising I suggest rather than create your own lead sheets get yourself a good fake book (Sher has some excellent ones although there are many others too) or if you only want chords get the iReal app for a few bucks and download free chord progressions for songs in the forums. You can literally download hundreds at a time. They are not always completely accurate but they can be edited and transposed easily. The benefit to using one of these two methods is you will not have to decipher the old ways of writing harmony and chords in the early 20th century and you will get versions that are in line with how these songs are performed and played today.

Comment: One factor that complicates such editorial decisions is that not all chord voicings are created equal.  If a piece of music will sound reasonable but somewhat bland with almost any voicing of chord X, and some voicings of chord Y will sound better but others will sound horrible, should a publisher list chord X or Y?

Comment: @supercat I believe the sheet music should be an accurate representation of the actual song so my vote in general terms would be for chord Y. A musician reading chord symbols has to try and be a little logical and sensible in their choices. A chord that is voiced badly, for example putting the 3rd above the 9th on a minor 9th chord or the tonic above the major 7th on a maj7th chord will sound bad in any context.

Comment: Some chord voicings will sound bad in any context, but there are some chord voicings that will sound good in some contexts but not others.  Further, in something like a piano-vocal-guitar arrangement, the optimal chords for use when performing with both a guitar and a bass may be different from the optimal chords that could be performed by a guitar when no bass player is present.

Comment: Also, what chord symbol should one write if a measure would sound okay with a triad strummed for a whole measure, and would sound better with a bass note played on the first beat and the rest of a seventh chord strummed on the second beat, but it wouldn't good with seventh chord strummed on the first beat, nor with a triad strummed on the first beat and a seventh chord strummed on the second?

Comment: @supercat I can't tell if you're offering criticism of this post -- i.e., looking for the post to be revised -- or if you're just adding additional commentary on the difficulties of arranging.

Comment: @Aaron: My intention was to suggest additional reasons for variations in chord symbols between different arrangements which you could mention in your answer if you think that useful.  I could write my own answer, but I'm not sure the extra information would be worthy being posted as an answer in its own right.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBelzaguy. I was basing my lead sheets on arrangements like this hoping that I'd be closer to the original 1930's compositions than the Berklee style of the 1970's, which is what I heard the Real Books are. But after seeing some of the variations here, I'm just like  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Kevin, I understand your reasoning. If I want to get to the nuts and bolts of a particular song I’ll look at a sheet if o have one then listen to a few different recordings and compare them all.

Comment: @supercat Your points are valid but the elements you described are really arrangements, not things that can be dictated or distinguished just by chord symbols.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy: My point is that most chord tabs are intended to be combined with rhythm and note arrangements at the performer's discretion, and the choice of what chords would work best with a piece may be affected by how one expects the performer to fill such details.  As a more concrete example, in Cm, if a melody descends Ab-G-F with the G on a downbeat that represents the start of a dominant chord, the part that's performing the chords should avoid having the top note be an F on the downbeat, or being a G on beat 2 unless that same note was played on beat 1, and...

Comment: ...should be cautious about excessively noticeable parallel octaves if the rhythm part moves G-F at the same time as the melody.  For some rhythm patterns, a G triad might sound better than G7, and for others the G7 would sound better.  Which chord would work better in the tab would depend upon how a performer would interpret each one.

Answer (score 10):

The arranger or editor will make those decisions. Often they are simplifications
(or someone's idea of a simplification) or clarifications, sometimes alternative harmonizations, sometimes the composer created different versions, sometimes they are based on particular recordings that differ from each other, sometimes they're just mistakes (I'm looking at you, *Real Book*).